# Connection of eigenspace of finite Hilbert matrix and its continuous operator counterpart

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, numerical-linear-algebra, eigenvector

I am trying to understand the connection between the eigenspace of the continuous operator
$$
H(x,y) = \frac{1}{x+y}
$$
which is nothing but the square of the Laplace operator, and its discrete counterpart, i.e. the Hilbert matrix
$$
H_{i,j} = \frac{1}{i+j}\,, i,j=1,\dots,N \,.
$$
In particular, [it can be proven](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ecle/papers/laplce_rev2.pdf) that the generalized eigenfunctions of the continuous operator are
$$
u_s(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} x^{-\frac{1}{2}+is}\,, \int_0^\infty dy \, H(x,y) u_s(y) = \vert \lambda_s \vert^2 u_s(x)
$$
where
$$
\lambda_s = \Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+is)\,, \quad \vert \lambda_s \vert^2 = \frac{\pi}{\cosh{\pi s}} \,.
$$
Intuitively, the discretized spectrum and eigenvectors should converge to their continuous values, but I do not fully understand nor find in the literature a discussion about the two distinct effects of

1. discretization, i.e. $i,j=1,2,\dots$, possibly up to $\infty$, and
2. finite, but continuous extension (i.e. having $\int_0^X$ rather than $\int_0^\infty$).

I believe their effects need to be taken separately into account, since considering an infinite but not continuous amount of points leads to some contradictions, e.g. if we consider the trace of the continuous vs the discrete Hilbert operator we obtain
$$
\mathrm{tr}{H} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty ds \, \vert \lambda_s \vert^2 = \pi < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+n} = \infty \,.
$$

I was wondering whether there was a way to link finite and discrete (i.e. numerical) eigenvalues of the Hilbert matrix to their continuous operator counterpart. Thank you all!

**EDIT**

Additional question: since the spectrum of the continuous Hilbert operator $H(x,y) = \frac{1}{x+y}$, $x,y\in(0,\infty)$ is absolutely continuous in $[0,\pi]$ and the spectrum of the infinite Hilbert matrix $H_{ij}=\frac{1}{i+j}$, $i,j=1,2,\dots$ [has the same property](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372284), what is the crucial difference between the two (besides the obvious discretization of indices)? If studying the infinite Hilbert matrix is not enough to recover the continuous Hilbert operator, what should complement the study of their spectrum, which is identical?

Comment: Numerical approximation of spectra is tricky. Arveson wrote a [good paper on this](https://math.berkeley.edu/~arveson/oldDvi/numlinalg.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @NikWeaver for the reference. I am not sure I understood it fully, but it appears to me that the case of the Hilbert matrix, maybe due to its ill-conditioning, might be pathological. Referring to the condition just above the beginning of Section 4, and considering the simplest filtration (the restriction of the values of $i,j=1,\dots,N < \infty$), this condition seems to hold only for the case of $\lambda=0$, which is the only accumulation point of the spectrum. Furthermore, this discussion only considers discretization, from which the absolutely continuous spectrum can never be seen...

Comment: Additionally, if I understood it correctly, the criterion for the spectrum of a matrix $A$ to be recovered from its discretization is that $\sum_k \vert k \vert^{1/2} d_k < \infty$, with $d_k$ the sup norm of the $k^\mathrm{th}$ diagonal. In the case of the Hilbert matrix numerical approximation of the spectra should not work, since the above sup is $\frac{1}{k+1}$ and thus the sum does not converge. Also, I added a comment on the main text above regarding discretization, if you want to have a look at it. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm on a trip and don't have time to look at this closely, sorry! My off-the-cuff reaction is that numerical approximation of the Hilbert matrix may be problematic ...

Comment: Thanks again, @NikWeaver! That is my impression as well. In case you have some time when you get back, let me know your thoughts on it!